# Why is AdMob integration in my app using Android Studio not working?

Tags: android, admob, android-studio

I integrated AdMob in my app using Eclipse Juno - it is working fine. But when I tried to integrate it using Android Studio, I get this error:

> Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize').

I also added jar file in libs folder. I use minSdk =9 and targetSdk=18. I also changed project.properties file to "target=android-13".

Answer (score 1):

screenSize and smallestScreenSize were only added in API 13. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

I presume you are getting this error when building the app? Change your build config so that you are building against version 13 or up of the SDK.

Comment: I changed project properties to "target=android-13". But still error is not solved.

Comment: No don't change the target attribute. Change the version of the Android SDK library in Android Studio config that you are using to build against.

Answer (score 0):

Check your target api level and minimum api level. i had similar issue before and i solved it like this:

target api level = highest available

minimum api level = 9

I dont know much about Android studio but you can do it from manifest.xml

i hope it helps.

Comment: My minimum api = 9 and targetSDK =18. "screenSize|smallestScreenSize" is not accepting to add.